Load local html file in Android flutter - race problem
I made simple app that loads local html files from assets.
The html are often not loading correctly, specialy simple pages and text does not appear. When refreshing the screen (like touching or changing the volume) it apears correctly.
I think it is a race problem where the webview gets rendered before the layout. I partially solved it with adding delay but it is not always working.
The problem did not appear on the emulator, it appears on samsung deviecs.
Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String htmlPath;

  WebViewPage({required this.htmlPath});

  @override
  _WebViewPageState createState() => _WebViewPageState();
}

class _WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {
  late final WebViewController _controller;
  
  get platform => null;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


    _controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);

      // Wait for the first frame to render before loading the HTML
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      // Wait just a bit more after the first frame
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
      _controller.loadFlutterAsset(widget.htmlPath);
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebView'),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller),
    );
  }


}


I added this to somehow hack the problem (not always works)
      // Wait for the first frame to render before loading the HTML
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      // Wait just a bit more after the first frame
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
      _controller.loadFlutterAsset(widget.htmlPath);
    });

